# To know the starting character and replacing with some other in python

Tags: python, string

I have some python code in which I am retrieving data from a database.
The column I am interested in is a URL which is in the format:

```
../xxxx/ggg.com
```

I need to find out if the first charactor is a `.`.
If it is a `.` I need to remove the two dots `..` at the beginning of the string and then append another string to it.
And finally i have to generate an xml file.

```
 This is my code:
    xml.element("Count","%s" %(offercount))
    for colm in offer:
        xml.start("Offer")
        xml.element("qqq","%s" %(colm[0]))
        xml.element("aaaa","%s" %(colm[1]))
        xml.element("tttt","%s" %(colm[2]))
        xml.element("nnnnnn","%s" %(colm[3]))      

        xml.element("tttt","%s" %(colm[4]))----> This colm[4] is the string with ..
        xml.end()
```

I am new to Python, Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: string.find & string.replace will help you http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: Thanks avasal..But string.find means it will checjk whereever ..(2 dots) appear in the string it will replace..But i don't want that..should remove the ..(2dots) in starting portion of the string only..

Comment: find function returns you the index where it is found, you can always match it with 0

Comment: It seems to me you are asking two questions. You are looking to determine if a string starts with two periods (..) and then secondly you want to generate some XML. The second part about generating XML isn't very clear. Perhaps you could clarify the second portion.

Comment: Thanks zzzirk..my question is i have to replace teh ..( 2 dots) in the string and i have to append some string to that and i have to generate an xml..

Comment: @prakash.k: i have added a simple answer for you make use of.. check it out

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression, e.g. `re.sub(r'^\.\.', '', old_string)`.  Regular expressions are a powerful way of matching strings, so in the example above, the regular expression `^\.\.` matches the start of a string (`^`) followed by two dots, which need to be escaped using `\` since `.` on its own actually matches anything.  A more complete example to do what I think you want:

```
import re
if re.match(r'^\.\.', old_string):
    new_string = old_string[2:] + append_string
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html for more info on regular expressions.

Comment: He's completely new to this, you'll probably have to elaborate. This is not really an answer as it does not address the appending issue. Also, why not `string.replace('.','')`?

Answer (score 1):

you can keep it simple like this

```
In [116]: colm = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '..heythere']

In [117]: str = colm[4]

In [118]: if str.find('..') == 0:
   .....:     print "found .. at the start of string"
   .....:     x = str.replace('..', '!')
   .....:     print x
   .....:
found .. at the start of string
!heythere
```

Comment: this string.replace replace all the occurrence of `..` with the given string.. if you have `..` only at the beginning, above solution should be fine

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you utilize the built in string handling functions `startswith()` and `replace()`:

```
if col.startswith('..'):
    col = col.replace('..', '')
```

Or perhaps, if you simply wish to remove the two periods at the beginning of the string you could do something like this:

```
if col.startswith('..'):
    col = col[2:]
```

This of course is assuming that you have only two periods at the beginning and that you wish to simply remove those two periods from the string.

Comment: thanks zzzirk..This is my java logic ..what i ahve to do this for python..if(aaa.startsWith("."))
//                        {
//                            int startindex = aaa.indexOf("/");
//                            aaa= aaa.substring(startindex,aaa.length());
//                            System.out.println("enter print url:"+aaa);
//                        } I have to get the remaining string without ..(2 dots)..

Comment: If there is a single period at the beginning of the string are there always TWO periods? The logic to use startswith('..') seems like it works just as well as startswith('.') does it not? In your Java code you are simply removing the periods, is that correct?

Comment: zzzirk..this is my code:col=colm[4]
        if(col.startsWith("..")):
  newcol = col[2:]
  Image="xxxxxxx.com" + newcol ..But it is showing the following error:File "offersubbu.cgi", line 34, in ?
if(col.startsWith("..")):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startsWith'

Comment: startswith() is all lowercase. It is not camelCase as it is in Java.